# Ubuntu installer cannot find hard disk

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, installation, acer-aspire

I bought an Acer laptop and immediately tried to install Linux but it does not recognize my hard disk. In BIOS, two hard disks are listed: HDD0 and HDD1. Interestingly enough, the HDD0 entry is empty and HDD1 entry holds the value of the hard disk. I think this is why Ubuntu installer cannot find the hard disk. It boots up, but when I choose to install Ubuntu, and it takes me to the point I'm supposed to choose where to install it, there is nothing there. It only has `/dev/sda` in greyed out, but `/dev/sda` is the bootable usb.

I have tried several solutions from the internet, (e.g., turn off secure boot, switch from RAID to ACHI, turn off fast boot, etc.), but nothing worked. There are other solutions I haven't tried because they could wipe the hard disks and I have exams going on so can't loose the Windows however dirty using it makes me feel.

I'm asking here in case someone faced the same problem. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: Here are some screenshots of the BIOS screen and the Disks utility.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129269/discussion-on-question-by-klaus-ubuntu-installer-cannot-find-hard-disk).

Comment: Check `lspci -k` to see if your AHCI controller is detected at all and if a driver is being used. Also look for hints in `dmesg` / `journalctl -k`.